# When does product of derivatives equals derivative of products?

Tags: calculus

In general, $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x) \cdot g(x)) \neq  \frac{d}{dx}f(x) \cdot \frac{d}{dx}g(x)$

When does this result hold true? My first try is to use product rule on left side and compare the two sides, but this hasn't helped at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: If $f(x)=g(x)=e^{2x}$, this is true.

Comment: is that an exhaustive list?

Comment: See the answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10927/when-do-the-freshmans-dream-product-and-quotient-rules-for-differentiation-hold?rq=1) for other examples.

Answer (score 12):

well assuming one of the two functions, e.g. $g$ is given, then finding $f$ is just solving a homogeneous linear equation.

$$f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x) = f'(x)g'(x)$$
which is the same as
$$f'(x)(g(x)-g'(x)) + f(x)g'(x) = 0$$
given $g$ then you can solve it by
$$f(x) = f(x_0)\exp \left\{ -\int_{x_0}^x \frac{g'(y)}{g(y)-g'(y)}dy\right\}.$$

Comment: It's not my own answer. Apparently this person didn't accept any answer... which is a problem, people ask and don't read the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

One can try the exponential of the form 
$f(x) = e^{ax}$ and $g(x)= e^{bx}$, then

$(fg)' = f'g+fg' = e^{ax}e^{bx}(a+b)=^! f'g'=  ae^{ax}be^{bx}\Leftrightarrow a+b = ab\Leftrightarrow a,b = 0 \lor a,b =  2. $