# Freshman's Dream Quotient Rule

Tags: calculus

I have been researching the Freshman's Dream Quotient Rule for awhile now and have been unable to find an example for which the rule works. I want to know if anyone knows of 2 function which it works for.

Rule is:

$$\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)'=\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

Comment: $ f(x)=g(x)=x $

Comment: @KennyLau Then $(f/g)' = 0$ but $f'/g' = 1$

Comment: Yes 0 and 1 would be the answers. So that one would not work.

Comment: That is wrong, because one side would give me -4/x^2 and the other side would give me 0.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10927/when-do-the-freshmans-dream-product-and-quotient-rules-for-differentiation-hold?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks, I just found it odd it does not hold. I thought maybe it was a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Define the functions $f$ and $g$ on $[1,+\infty]$.

$f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=x$, so $f'(x)=0$ and $g'(x)=1$.

$$\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)'=\left(\frac{0}{x}\right)'=0'=0$$

$$\frac{f(x)'}{g(x)'}=\frac{0}{1}=0$$