# Quotient Rule, finding a special case

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Quotient rule for functions is straightforward: $g(x)/h(x)$

Can I find a pair of functions not constant where the quotient of the derivative is the derivative of the quotient?

Comment: what do you mean by "quotient of the derivative"? Do you mean $f'/g'$?

Comment: Yes! That's what I meant

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/10927/120540 . There, the question asks in addition for $(f \cdot g)' = f' \cdot g'$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose neither $f$ nor $g$ vanish. We need a function such that 
$$
f'/g' = (gf'-fg')/g^2.
$$

Thus

$$
g^2f' = gg'f' - f(g')^2 \rightarrow g(g'-g)f' = f(g')^2 \rightarrow f'/f = \frac{(g')^2}{(g'-g)g},
$$
and therefore
$$
\ln f = \int\frac{(g')^2}{(g'-g)g}dx.
$$

Putting in $g(x) = e^{-x}$ gives $f(x) = e^{x}$ which gives the desired behavior.