# The differential equation $u'(x)v(x) + u(x)v'(x) = u'(x)v'(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What are all solutions to the differential equation

$$ u'(x)v(x) + u(x)v'(x) = u'(x)v'(x) $$

Where the derivative is with respect to $x$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  Is there any particular motivation for this problem?

Comment: So $v$ is known and you want to solve for $u$? If you change to $U = \log u - x$ and $V = \log v - x$ then we have $U'V' = 1$.

Comment: see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10927/when-do-the-freshmans-dream-product-and-quotient-rules-for-differentiation-hold?rq=1