A very specific integral
So, as many students make a mistake of $(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})'= \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$, professor asked a silly question - try to find all the functions $f,g$ that truly satisfy this equation. This was asked as a joke, but for some reason it got stuck in my head - is there truly a way to do this? What I tried obviously is $\frac{f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{(g(x))^2} = \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ and then multiply both sides with $(g(x))^2g'(x)$ to get $f'(x)g(x)g'(x)-f(x)(g'(x))^2=f'(x)(g(x))^2$, so $f'(x)(g(x)g'(x)-(g(x))^2) = f(x)(g'(x))^2$, so $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{(g'(x))^2}{g(x)g'(x)-g^2(x)}$, so $\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx = \int \frac{(g'(x))^2}{g(x)g'(x)-g^2(x)}dx$, and on the left side we obviously have $\ln|f(x)|$. But what in the world is integral on the right side? I try various things but nothing works. All ideas are welcome! Thankies and sowwy if only interesting to me!

I suggest starting by looking for examples.  If $f(x)=cg(x)$, for some constant $c$, that works.  So now look for cases where the ratio is not constant.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/10927/42969
